# Sharing data between 2 Vue projects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, razor-pages

So to make it really simple, because of the way we're using Vue, we have 2 different projects running in html.partials. A:In my layout of the page, and B: a page which show a list of results

A: recieves data from an API, in this case a bool

B: I want to disable/enable button depending on the bool

I've tried simple state management https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch which did not work
I've tried EventBus
I've tried saving in sessionStorage and using Getters and Seets, eventhandlers, and various packages to get a "sessionStorageChanged" event. Nothing.

Is it really not possible for me to get data from app.Axxxx to app.Bxxxx?

Comment: Is B an iFrame? Are they running on the same domain?
Are A and B two separate Vue apps running in the same HTML page?

Comment: B is not an iframe.
They are 2 seperate Vue apps, but A my layout, and B is just a partial view

Comment: I think you need to share some code. An EventBus is typically quite a simple way for anything in js to communicate with something else so it would seem odd if that would not work when implemented correctly.